# Jsoup - Parsing html child element

Tags: parsing, jsoup, element

i have this html structure:

```
<div class="wrapper-a">
    <li class="list"><h3>Text1</h3></li>    
    <li class="list"><h3>Text2</h3></li>
    <li class="list"><h3>Text3</h3></li>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-b">
    <li class="list"><h3>Text4</h3></li>    
    <li class="list"><h3>Text5</h3></li>
    <li class="list"><h3>Text6</h3></li>
</div>
```

I need to get alls Text´s from list´s with ".wrapper-a" parent:

```
Elements links = doc.select("div[class=wrapper-a] > li[class=list]");
for (Element link : links)
{
    Elements lists_s = link.select("h3");
    String list_s = lists_s.text();

    System.out.println(list_s);
}
```

What i expected to see:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

No error occurring, but also no output printed.

Anybody could help me with this?
Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this selector:

```
Elements links = doc.select("div.wrapper-a li");
```

It should work.

Bytheway I think you are using an old version of JSoup, with a modern version (>= 1.7.1) your code works fine as it is.